# Does Derby database not support columnDefinition="LONGTEXT" in @Column annotation?

Tags: java, jpa, junit, derby

I am using embedded Apache Derby database for JUnit tests. I have some JPA entities. There are entities containing columns like this:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String rawResults;
```

It all works with embedded Derby, until I got tired of replacing `TEXT` into `LONGTEXT` in the queries generated by `openjpa-maven-plugin`, so I made that column like this:

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String rawResults;
```

Now `openjpa-maven-plugin` is generating `LONGTEXT` instead of `TEXT`. But this only works while I am skipping my tests.

Then I run my tests and Derby takes place so everything fails with the errors like this:

```
org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: TYPE 'LONGTEXT' does not exist. {stmnt 23146419 CREATE TABLE Assessment -- Assessment_JpaImpl
```

I am using Derby 10.9.1.0 and I as far as I understand it does not support `columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT"`. Is this right? Or I need to set up some configuration that make derby support this attribute?

Comment: You do realise that "columnDefinition" will be totally specific to one RDBMS? so you throw away portability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the Derby datatypes: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/crefsqlj31068.html#crefsqlj31068